# deallocation order of the static member and detached thread itself

Tags: c++, libcurl

There is a global function that initializes and cleans up some resources.
But those 2 function must be called when no other thread is running.(like `curl_global_init`)
Initializer must be manually called, but I don't want the cleaner to be called manually.
So I do the following.

```
class GLOBAL_WRAPPER {
 public:
  static void init() {
    getInstance();
  }

  static GLOBAL_WRAPPER& getInstance() {
    static GLOBAL_WRAPPER inst;
    return inst;
  }

 private:
  GLOBAL_WRAPPER() {
    // do global init call
  }
  ~GLOBAL_WRAPPER() {
    // do global cleanup call
  }
};

void GLOBAL_INIT() {
  GLOBAL_WRAPPER::init();
}



int main(){
  GLOBAL_INIT();

  // do whatever you want

  // std::thread([](){for(;;);}).detach(); oops!
}
```

But in such bad case like: creating detached thread and not terminating it before `main` ends, when is deallocation of static variables(`GLOBAL_WRAPPER` in this case) called?

1. detached thread is terminated and static variable is freed
2. static variable is freed and detached thread is terminated
3. implementation defined.

I'm just interested in the *thread* itself, not thread storage duration objects.

Comment: I must admit that I didn't read further than "detached thread" and "order". You do know that you absolutely need to implement most of what's covered in the standard by _not_ detaching the thread and just joining it when it's appropriate?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes I know that. But this program is running on mobile devices, and I'm not the only one who's maintaining this code. So I want it to be as safe as possible.

Comment: Ok, but _safe_ and detached threads sounds like a contradiction. I find attached threads tricky enough even though I use them on a daily basis. You get sort of everything for free with a joinable thread. What problem is detaching it solving?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah, it would be best if those situations never happens. But my co-worker write a codes that run threads in detached mode, and checking if it's destructed by sleeping and checking in infinite loop. I bet my co-worker will make mistakes one day.

Comment: If the threads are detached, there's no Standard-approved way to tell if the threads are still running. For something like this I would consider using `std::shared_ptr`. You can clear out the global one and it'll vanish once all the threads using it have gone out of scope. You could even make a new global one to hand to new threads if you want to. Maybe hold a `weak_pointer` and not allow exiting until the `weak_ptr`  cannot be locked.

Comment: Your coworker is already making mistakes, by the sound of it, so that day has come. They should be on the block to support that madness.

Comment: You could try arguing with them. `join()`ing vs. `detach()`ing ... Detaching I would say is left for ninjas. I'm not one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ standard specifies (in so many words) that returning from `main` is equivalent to calling `std::exit`.

> main function [basic.start.main]
>
> A return statement in main has the effect of leaving the main function
> (destroying any objects with automatic storage duration) and calling
> std::exit with the return value as the argument. If control flows off
> the end of the compound-statement of main, the effect is equivalent to
> a return with operand 0.

`exit` is defined as follows (irrelevant details omitted):

> Startup and termination [support.start.term]
>
> [[noreturn]] void exit(int status);
>
> Effects:
>
> — First, objects with thread storage duration and associated
> with the current thread are destroyed. Next, objects with static
> storage duration are destroyed and functions registered by calling
> atexit are called.
>
> — Next, all open C streams ... are removed.
>
> — Finally, control is returned to the host environment. If status is
> zero or EXIT_SUCCESS, an implementation-defined form of the status
> successful termination is returned. If status is EXIT_- FAILURE, an
> implementation-defined form of the status unsuccessful termination is
> returned.

It is not defined what happens if non-main execution threads are running when the main execution thread returns. The shown code does not guarantee that the non-main execution thread terminates/sequenced before `main` returns.

As such, the only thing the standard specifies is that:

1. Global objects get destroyed
2. "Control is returned to the host environment", a.k.a.: "It's dead, Jim".

The standard does not define what happens if non-main execution threads are running when the main execution thread returns. A.k.a.: undefined behavior.

Comment: "_It is not behavior as we know or understand it. Yet it is obviously behaving, it exists_" / Kirkish

Comment: @Ted More Spockish, if you consider [The Firm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCARADb9asE) to be cannon.